# get the child key for specific value when append table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i created a table and used Jquery to put all the user database from firebase info in it. The problem is: i have a button in the table that be should when you click the button console print the element key from database.

```
var userDataRef = firebase.database().ref("User/3N2f2rJSSAZmFOdZEeJdlsuEZam2").orderByKey();

userDataRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
  var key = childSnapshot.key;
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();         
  var title_val = childData.Title;
  var url_val = childData.Url;
    // Append data
    $("#data").append("<tr><td>" + title_val + "</td><td><a href=" + url_val + " target='_blank'> <button class='box'>GO</button></a></td><td><button id='del' class='box'>Delete</button></a></td><</tr>");


    $('#data').on('click', '#del', function(){
        console.log(key)
      });
```

```
                <table border="0" style="height: 63px; width: 100%;"> 
                    <thead> 
                        <tr> 
                            <div class="column middle" style="background-color:#f8f8f8;">
                            <td>Title</td> 
                            <td style="width: 40%;" >Link</td> 
                            <td style="width: 10%;" >Delete</td> 
                            </div>
                        </tr>                     
                    </thead>                 
                    <tbody id="data" > 
                  </tbody>                 
                  </table>
```

when this function perform i gut all the keys not just the one from the exact raw

```
$('#data').on('click', '#del', function(){
        console.log(key)
      });
```

```
output : 
-LkT_afLi9nfn65OS2QJ database.js:17:17
-LkTciKQVEa2bsbtSwkW database.js:17:17
-LkTclDO8dYSBfgiBjAZ
```

Comment: You should not repeat ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding to all the elements and you are duplicating ids. Ids are singular.

You would be better off with either binding to the one button alone or event delegation with a data attribute.

```
userDataRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
  /* cut out the vars */ 
  var myRow = $("<tr><td>" + title_val + "</td><td><a href=" + url_val + " target='_blank'> <button class='box'>GO</button></a></td><td><button class='box'>Delete</button></a></td></tr>");
  myRow.find("button").on("click", function(){
    console.log(key)
  });
  $("#data").append(myRow);
});
```

or event delegation with a data attribute

```
$("#data").on("click", "button[data-key]", function(evt){
  var btn = $(this);
  console.log(btn.data("key"))
});

userDataRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
  /* cut out the vars */ 
  var myRow = $("<tr><td>" + title_val + "</td><td><a href=" + url_val + " target='_blank'> <button class='box'>GO</button></a></td><td><button class='box' data-key='" + key + "'>Delete</button></a></td></tr>");      
  $("#data").append(myRow);
});
```

Comment: it worked, i have been for three hours trying to solve that :) thank you , but how can the   myRow.find("button").on("click", function(){ know the button without ID or Class name ??

Comment: because it is the row that was just created and there is only one button.

Comment: what if there is more than one button ?  myRow.find("button") will select all buttons

Answer (score 0):

ID's should never be repeated, use the class of the buttons instead as a common attribute.